# How can i force to fire an error with selenium webdriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I force to fire an error using chromedriver with selenium webdriverIO? i don't know if there some script like browser.fire('error')?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
throw new Error('Error occurred');
```

This will throw an exception for the window and if not handled I believe you will get what you need.

Comment: Still it does not throw the exception and I use Sync mode with Cucumber Framework